# java jama matrix problem

Tags: java, math, matrix, jama

I am using [jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) to calculate SVD. It work very good. If i pass square matrix. For example 2x2 or 3x3 etc. matrix. But when I pass some thing like this 2x3 or 4x8 it give 
error . I used all of their example. They have different constructor to perform the job. Also my second question is, I am usded 3x3 matrix and it gave

```
double[][] vals = {{1.,1.,0},{1.,0.,1.},{1.,3.,4.},{6.,4.,8.}};
  Matrix A = new Matrix(vals);
```

It produced following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

After that I thaught to use another constructor that is as follow

```
double[][] vals = {{1.,1.,0,4},{1.,0.,1.,2},{1.,3.,4.,8},{1.,3.,4.,8}};
  Matrix A = new Matrix(vals,4,3);
```

It produced following output:

```
A = 
 1.0 1.0 0.0
 1.0 0.0 1.0
 1.0 3.0 4.0
 6.0 4.0 8.0

A = U S V^T

U = 
 0.078 -0.115 -0.963
 0.107 -0.281 0.260
 0.402 0.886 -0.018
 0.906 -0.351 0.060

Sigma = 
 11.861881 0.000000 0.000000
 0.000000 2.028349 0.000000
 0.000000 0.000000 1.087006

V = 
 0.507705 -0.795196 -0.331510
 0.413798 0.562579 -0.715735
 0.755650 0.226204 0.614675

rank = 3
condition number = 10.912437186202627
2-norm = 11.86188091889931
singular values = 
 11.861881 2.028349 1.087006
```

It worked for non square matrix. But it produced wrong results for svd because V and S doesn't have same rows=4 ( I am sorry if i couldn't analyze result properly as i am new for SVD) . Any idea?
What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful here, JAMA supports SVD primarily for full rank matrices, and if you read the "readme" you'll notice that the behavior is not necessarily correct for rank deficient (m < n) matrices.

In essence, what causes your ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception is line 486 in `SingularValueDecomposition`:

```
return new Matrix(U,m,Math.min(m+1,n));
```

Changing this to:

```
return new Matrix(U);
```

will solve the problem.  Ultimate what happens under the covers (at least for vicatcu's example) is that you inject a matrix with `m=4` and `n=5`, but notice in the actual output `U` has dimensions `m=4` and `n=4`.  If you read the top of the `SingularValueDecomposition` class it states:

> For an m-by-n matrix A with m >= n, the singular value decomposition is
>   an m-by-n orthogonal matrix U, an n-by-n diagonal matrix S, and
>   an n-by-n orthogonal matrix V so that A = U*S*V'.

But this doesn't hold in this case, because `m=4` and `n=5` means `m<n`.  So now since you're passing a rank deficient matrix U has different dimensions than the *normal* calling case of the SVD class, and as such the statement:

```
new Matrix(U, m, Math.min(m+1,n))
```

will create a matrix with assumed rows of `m`, here 4 (which is correct) and assumed columns `n`, here `Math.min(4+1,5)=5` (which is incorrect).  So: when you go print the matrix and the print routine calls `getColumnDimension`, the U matrix returns `5`, which is greater than the actual backing array dimension.

In short, switching to the line I pasted above will detect the dimensions of U, and as such return a valid result regardless of the rank.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I want to run multiple regression with jama and have the same problem. maybe my question is weird but I cannot edit SingularValueDecomposition class. It means netbeans do not let me edit the jama code.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [wiki article on SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values.2C_singular_vectors.2C_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD). The following code is representative of the example in Section 2.

```
import Jama.Matrix; 
import Jama.SingularValueDecomposition; 

public class JAMATest { 

    static public void printMatrix(Matrix m){
        double[][] d = m.getArray();

        for(int row = 0; row < d.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < d[row].length; col++){
                System.out.printf("%6.4f\t", m.get(row, col));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        double[][] vals = { {1., 0., 0., 0., 2.}, 
                            {0., 0., 3., 0., 0.}, 
                            {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
                            {0., 4., 0., 0., 0.} 
                          };  
        Matrix A = new Matrix(vals);         
        SingularValueDecomposition svd = new SingularValueDecomposition(A); 

        System.out.println("A = ");
        printMatrix(A);

        System.out.println("U = ");
        printMatrix(svd.getU());

        System.out.println("Sigma = ");
        printMatrix(svd.getS());

        System.out.println("V = ");
        printMatrix(svd.getV());
    } 
}
```

and yields the outputL:

```
A = 
1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  2.0000  
0.0000  0.0000  3.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
0.0000  4.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  

U = 
0.0000  0.0000  -1.0000 0.0000  
0.0000  1.0000  -0.0000 0.0000  
0.0000  0.0000  -0.0000 1.0000  
1.0000  0.0000  -0.0000 0.0000  

Sigma = 
4.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
0.0000  3.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
0.0000  0.0000  2.2361  0.0000  0.0000  
0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  

V = 
0.0000  -0.0000 -0.4472 -0.8944 -0.0000 
0.0000  -0.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000 
0.0000  1.0000  -0.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000 
0.0000  -0.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000 1.0000  
1.0000  -0.0000 -0.8944 0.4472  -0.0000
```

Hope this helps. Also, FWIW here is Matlab's output on the same problem:

```
>> A = [1.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  2.0000; 0, 0, 3, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 4, 0, 0, 0];
>> A

A =

     1     0     0     0     2
     0     0     3     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     4     0     0     0

>> [U, S, V] = svd(A);
>> U

U =

     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0    -1
     1     0     0     0

>> S

S =

    4.0000         0         0         0         0
         0    3.0000         0         0         0
         0         0    2.2361         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0

>> V

V =

         0         0    0.4472         0   -0.8944
    1.0000         0         0         0         0
         0    1.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0
         0         0    0.8944         0    0.4472
```

With regards to your first question, the following code produces no error:

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class JAMATest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] vals = {{1.,1.,0},{1.,0.,1.},{1.,3.,4.},{6.,4.,8.}}; 
        Matrix A = new Matrix(vals); 

    }
}
```

So something else you're doing must be causing it to have an exception. Try using my printMatrix method in place of whatever you are using and see if it helps.

Comment: I am sorry, but i couldn't understand your answer. Do you think the output i wrote in my question is correct? How much V and S has 3 rows? Can you please explain? I am sorry i am not math expert :(

Comment: modifications to my previous program above. I included my printMatrix function. Note that I got a similar exception as you did when I tried using m.getRowDimension() and m.getColumnDimension() as they don't appear to be accurate for the svd.getU() method. Converting the matrix to a double[][] seems to do the trick.

Comment: On a separate note, the SVD of a matrix is not unique. See this quote from the wikipedia article: "It should also be noted that this particular singular value decomposition is not unique." When you multiply U * S * V you will get the original Matrix back. The dimensions of a matrix sort of "join" when you multiply. So our original matrix was [4 x 5] = [4 x 4] * [4 x 5] * [5 x 5], and you're left with the outer two dimensions ([4 ..x.. 5]). It seems in you have to *recognize* that only the first four rows of Sigma are the actual matrix based on these properties.

Comment: @agazerboy, As you can see from the Matlab and Java output, columns 3 and 4 of U in the Matlab output differ in sign from the Java output -- this is acceptable, U forms an orthornormal basis, and as such any column may be negated, and this is acceptable.

Comment: Hello..I am getting all NAN value in singular S, lest singular U and Right singular V. Matrix is too big(146,534378). what could be the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of U, S and V do not need to be the same dimensions as A. U will have the same number of rows and V^T will have the same number of columns. That is sufficient to recreate A by the rules of matrix multiplication.

The other dimension (columns of U, rows of V^T and rows/columns of S) will be the "rank" of A (in your example 3). This is, roughly speaking, the dimensionality of your data...how many axes are needed to uniquely represent a column or row in A. It will be at most `min(rows, cols)` but can often be much less. That is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Jama don't support full SVD but only reduced SVD. It's equivalent Matlab svd(B,0) or svd(B,'econ'). Bye